# Elasticsearch's keyword tokenizer and searching for emails does not really work

Tags: email, search, elasticsearch

I have set up an index like this:

```
POST /testindex/ -d '
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "analyzer_keyword": {
                    "tokenizer": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "users": {
            "properties": {
                "email": {
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Now I have added some `users` documents to `testindex` whereas a user contains an email address. If I want to search for a user document by specifying the email address like the following, it does not really work as expected:

```
GET /testindex/users/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "email" : "hello@host.com" }
    }
}
```

This query returns 0 results. But if I say `"email": "hello"` or `"email": "host.com"` it returns the exact document. But what is wrong with the `@`? How can I search by the complete email address?

The elasticsearch [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html) says:
`A tokenizer of type keyword that emits the entire input as a single input.` The entire input is `hello@host.com`.

I also tried `uax_url_email` tokenizer. Does not work either.

Comment: Look strange, I can use your mapping and query without any problem, it return correct data for hello@host.com. I'm using ES 0.90.5. You can install plugin: https://github.com/jotitan/elasticsearch-inquisitor and check what actually indexed in your case (`hello`, `host.com` or `hello@host.com`)

Comment: Sorry @Duc.Duong didn't see your comment when I submitted my answer. But, I agree with you - it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work fine to me:

```
curl -XDELETE "localhost:9200/testindex?pretty"
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/testindex?pretty" -d '
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "analyzer_keyword": {
                    "tokenizer": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "users": {
            "properties": {
                "email": {
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/testindex/users?pretty&refresh" -d '{"email": "hello@host.com"}'
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/testindex/users/_search?pretty" -d '{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "email" : "hello@host.com" }
    }
}'
```

it returns:

```
{
  "error" : "IndexMissingException[[testindex] missing]",
  "status" : 404
}
{
  "ok" : true,
  "acknowledged" : true
}
{
  "ok" : true,
  "_index" : "testindex",
  "_type" : "users",
  "_id" : "GkPG9l83RGyeMyGM9x6ecQ",
  "_version" : 1
}
{
  "took" : 62,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.30685282,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "testindex",
      "_type" : "users",
      "_id" : "GkPG9l83RGyeMyGM9x6ecQ",
      "_score" : 0.30685282, "_source" : {"email": "hello@host.com"}
    } ]
  }
}
```

on both 0.90.7 and current master. Did you try to delete the index before changing the mapping?

Comment: In Google chrome's plugin Sense it works fine. But if I use a php client like https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle I get more than one result back, if I have i.e. `hello@host.com` and `hi@host.com`

Comment: Are you using GET or POST method for search in guzzle? If you are using GET, try it with POST to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: OMG, thats it. Thanks, I wouldn't have tried that, because searching is clearly GET. Do you have an explanation why it works with POST?

Comment: Some HTTP frameworks "think" that GET request isn't supposed to have body, so they omit it. When body is omitted, the search request becomes `match_all` and returns all records.